# Proxy Setting config do not save

Tags: windows, google-chrome

I've changed my proxy ecxeptions hunderes of time (Windows,chrome), but they resert after a while. What could be happening?

Answer (score 6):

**Step 1**: win + R > regedit

**Step 2**: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings

**Step 3**:double click `ProxySettingsPerUser` change the value to 1

Answer (score 3):

The problem was: (Some settings are managed by your administrator)

[image]

Solution:

Create registry: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\
CurrentVersion\Internet Settings -> ProxySettingsPerUser

Set its value to 1(enable)

Problem solve.

link: https://fixedit.itxpress.biz/2014/10/08/unable-to-disable-windows-proxy-setting/#comment-42527

Answer (score 1):

This is also happens when you insert the url as **http://siteurl/**, You just have to enter as **siteurl**